# binding a variable to the src tag of embed element for pdf zoom level capability in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf, embed

I have a component in my angular app where I want to remove the pdf viewer default toolbar and bind two component level functions to provide `zoom in/zoom out` capability. Here is my code in my `pdf-viewer.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdf-viewer',
  template: `
    <div style="background-color: palegreen; height: 100%; display: flex;">

    <embed type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" [src]="pdfSrc">
    <div>
      <button (click)="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
      <button (click)="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./pdf-viewer.component.css']
})
export class PdfViewerComponent {
  zoomLevel = 100; // Default zoom level
  pdfSrc: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.updatePdfSrc();
  }

  zoomIn() {
    this.zoomLevel += 5;
    this.updatePdfSrc();
  }

  zoomOut() {
    this.zoomLevel -= 5;
    this.updatePdfSrc();
  }

  private updatePdfSrc() {
    const unsafeUrl = `myPdf.pdf#toolbar=0&zoom=${this.zoomLevel}%`;
    this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(unsafeUrl);
  }
}
```

The problem I face is that every time I click `zoom In` or `zoom Out`, the whole embed HTML environment disappears.

My goal is to change the zoom level of the pdf display as per the code.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Thanks for the information @KJ, I meant to hide the toolbar of course. My target users are using Google Chrome (which already has a built-in pdf viewer service). I agree that for every zoom level step there is a single download (that's also ok from the host/client perspective). I appreciate if you have a better idea regarding this.